# How to make CSS - angles-image + background? And height - 100% or auto?

Tags: html, css, angle

I have already made CSS a lot of times, but did not work and a lot of glitches ...
**I will show picture - glitch:**
See picture - *http://beta.areku-developstudio.org.ua/new.png*

**See picture (this is necessary, as better quality):**
See picture2 - http://beta.areku-developstudio.org.ua/new2.png

How to make CSS - angles-image + background? And height - 100% or auto?
***Sample HTML:***

```
<div id="conteiner" class="main">
    <div class="top_left_corner">
        <div class="top_right_corner">
            <div class="bottom_left_corner">
                <div class="bottom_right_corner">
                    <div id="content">
                        <br/><br/>
                        Hello Areku<br/>
                        Hello Areku<br/>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Choose other ways to make CSS + HTML. Can jQuery? I am waiting for an answer ...
Sincerely, Areku!

Comment: Questions about webpage layout should be asked on doctype. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with some creative uses of the background property on your various elements:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="content">
        Your content
     </div>
     <div class="corner right"></div>
     <div class="corner left"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the CSS would be as follows:

```
/* Following 2 rules create min-height 100% for your content and body */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* html and body create the fixed position bottom right/left corners */
html {
  background: url(bottom-right.png) no-repeat fixed 100% 0;
}

body {
  background: url(bottom-left.png) no-repeat fixed 0 0;
}

/* top right/left corners are handled by 2 divs */
.corner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

  width: 50px;  /* width of your background image corner */
  height: 50px; /* height of your background image corner */    
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background: url(top-left.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: url(top-right.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}
```